# Android: Migrate Foreground Service to WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager, worker, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

My application uses location in the background. From Android 12 onwards, we are not supposed to use Foreground Service and if we use it, the application crashes with the below exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.xxx.sdk.location.tracking.xxx.xxx.xxxForegroundService@cb55d82 with Intent { cmp=xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.sdk.location.tracking.xxx.service.xxxForegroundService }: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.sdk.location.tracking.xxx.service.xxxForegroundService
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:5110)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:310)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2319)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

I have gone through the replacement of WorkManager and creating a notification using it.

My goal is to display long running foreground notification to a user as we are fetching location in background. I used WorkManager but the notification appears and disappears as I am not performing any task in **doWork()** method.

How can I show continuous foreground notification using WorkManager?

Comment: Yes, you can use work manager for this kind of tasks as Work Manager guarantees the task completion.

Comment: @KaranMehta Do you have any examples for that?

Comment: @KaranMehta I tried with WorkManager but when the doWork() returns success, the notification disappears at it assumes that task is completed.

Comment: You can use foreground service as well to do so and it works fine as well, You just need to ask permission for push notification & foreground service and also you need to add android:foregroundServiceType="location" in the manifest inside your service tag.

Comment: @KaranMehta I got this crash for Android 12 and above. It is mentioned in Android 12 behavior changes that "If you discover that your app starts foreground services while running from the background, update your app's logic to use WorkManager." Currently, I am using Foreground service only but I faced this crash and that's why moved to WorkManager. But, now I am facing issue with showing foreground notification for infinity time.

Comment: Have you tried adding the flag and permission that I suggested?

Comment: @KaranMehta Yes, I already did that.

Comment: Do you use `Kotlin` or `Java`?

Comment: @Zain I am using Java.

Comment: If you're using Kotlin of even you mix that in the same project you'd go for `CoroutineWorker` which combines both WorkManager and Foreground service https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running

Comment: There is a hard Job timeout defined in the code for each Job, after that time system will stop it.